# a thing pretty much straight out of high school

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I really cannot understand what author means from the highlighted part in this sentence:

> getting into careers, I discovered that pen testing was a **thing
> pretty much straight out of high school**

Comment: Perhaps 'something that a school-leaver could do without any further training'?

Comment: On the other hand, I read it as "something you do in high school, but that shouldn't be relevant for adults". We can't tell without context.

Comment: And I read it as "Immediately upon leaving high school, I discovered this thing."  I don't think it's a very well-written sentence.

Comment: Yup. At least three possible meanings without more context. So please add the surrounding context so someone can give a confident answer rather than a series of guesses.

Answer (score 1):

I would interpret this as "When I was pretty much straight out of high school, I discovered that pen testing is 'a thing' (a career that one could pursue)."

Comment: Assuming pen testing is the concept from cyber-security then your reading seems to me spot on.

Answer (score 0):

It's very colloquial. Let's try to break it down…

**Getting into** - 'regarding', 'moving onto this topic'. 'Let's talk about this next'. It may also be 'moving on towards'. Getting into careers could be 'acquiring my job'. 'The journey I took towards my career.' It's hard to tell without further context.

**pen testing**, if you didn't know, is professional 'hacking' - penetration testing. Literally being paid to try to break into computer/online systems to discover vulnerabilities in security, on behalf of the software/web structure owners.

**a thing** - it 'exists'. It is 'a thing, an object, a job/career', in this case a job in computer security.

**pretty much** - is 'almost, nearly'. The phrase conveys an 'amount' or a large percentage of the possible total. "The glass was pretty much full"… or "pretty much empty", in this instance an 'amount of time' referred to in the next part…

**straight out of high school** -  in this case 'straight' is a 'short or direct journey'. "I went straight from the bus stop to the Library" implies you took no diversions from the most direct route, you didn't call off to get an ice cream on the way. Equally it can apply to 'time' -  "I went straight from school to my first job. I left school Friday & started work the following Monday" - immediately on leaving education they joined the job market, they didn't take a year off first.

So…

> I discovered that this job existed as a potential career very soon after I left school.